# VBA loop through workbooks + copy&paste

Tags: excel, vba, loops, copy-paste

I would like to take data from different workbooks (which have the same structure) and create a loop to copy&paste the data retrieved in the active workbook. I tried this but it doesn't work.

```
Sub loopMacro()
Dim Wb1 As Workbook, Wb2 As Workbook, Wb3 As Workbook
Dim MainBook As Workbook

'Open all workbooks:
Set Wb1 = Workbooks.Open("D:\VBA\file1.xlsx")
Set Wb2 = Workbooks.Open("D:\VBA\file2.xlsx")
Set Wb3 = Workbooks.Open("D:\VBA\file3.xlsx")
Set MainBook = ThisWorkbook

For i = 1 To 3
        For j = A To C
            WB(i).Sheets("sheet1").Range("E4").Copy
            MainBook.Sheets("DATA").Range(j & "1").PasteSpecial
            WB(i).Sheets("sheet1").Range("E5").Copy
            MainBook.Sheets("DATA").Range(j & "2").PasteSpecial
        Next j
Next i

MainBook.Save
MainBook.Close End Sub
```

Basically the macro should take the data from sheet 1 - cells E4 and E5 of Wb1, Wb2, Wb3... and print the data of Wb1 in the active workbook (cells A1 and A2), the data of Wb2 in cells B1 and B2, the data of Wb3 in cells C1 and C2.
Somebody can help?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that WB(i) does not result in Wb1, Wb2 etc.

Replace the `for i` with

```
For Each wb In Array(Wb1, Wb2, Wb3)
```

and then all `wb(i)` with `wb`

Comment: Many thanks! :)
What about the loop for the cells? 
The idea is to write the copied data in range A1:C2...

Comment: A to C means "from the value of A (=0) to C (also = 0)". Use Cells(row, col) instead

Comment: Thanks! Small problem...now the macro is opening the first workbook, copying and pasting in the right place, but then it opens the second workbook and overwrite the previous values with the new ones and so on...it souldn't overwrite but print the first values in column A, the second in column B and the last in column C...